# Add "nomodule" attribute dynamically to the <script nomodules src="abc.com">

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to generate the script tag like this dynamically:
  .

for 'async' and 'defer' I know we can do the following:
we can do "s.async=true" or "s.defer=true" just like following.

```
  function script(url) {
            var s = document.createElement('script');

            s.async = true;
            s.src = url; 
            console.log(s);
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            x.appendChild(s);
          }
```

to get dynamically generated tag like 
 `<script async src="abc.com"></script>`

But for 'nomodules', I didn't have the desired result.
I tried to do "s.nomodule=true" but to no avail.
I tried doing the following.

```
 function script(url) {
            var s = document.createElement('script');

            s.nomodule = true;
            s.src = url; 
            console.log(s);
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            x.appendChild(s);
          }
```

but I only got `<script src="abc.com"></script>`

How can I get result like

`<script nomodule src="abc.com"></script>` dynamically.

Comment: Thanks T.J.Crowder... I have edited the question... Please help if you know the solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The property is called [`noModule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement). Unlike HTML, JavaScript is case-sensitive!

```
function script(url) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');

    s.noModule = true;
//      ^
    s.src = url; 
    console.log(s);
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    x.appendChild(s);
}
```

Alternatively, `s.setAttribute("nomodule", "")` would have worked as well.